How to efficiently get the row index of the last non-empty cell in a column in Google Sheet
Is there a way to efficiently obtain the row index of the last non-empty cell in a column in Google Sheet?
The column may contain blank cells in between or cells that fail isblank() but checks ="".
Example
App Script solution is ok but would be cumbersome. But note that other columns of the same sheet contain non-empty cells of larger rows.

I understand tocol is great for retrieving the content of the last non-empty cell. Is there a built-in function that can do for row index of that cell?

This works. Unsure of efficiency.
=row(index(A:A,max(not(isblank(A:A))*row(A:A))))

Note that the output of index can be used as range arguments. e.g. A2:index(A:A,max(not(isblank(A:A))*row(A:A))) gives the range below header.

In case of performance, this formula =REDUCE(0,A:A,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(x<>"",ROW(x),a))) may be faster.

Use xmatch(), like this:
=arrayformula(xmatch("?*", to_text(A:A), 2, -1))

See xmatch().

If it is text data type column then use-
=MATCH("zzz",A:A)

If the column is number data type then use-
=MATCH(99^9,H:H)



Thanks! The caveat being words should not start with zzz such as zzzSleeeepyzzZ right?


Here's 2 suggestions:
match
(personally use this most)
=A2:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>"")))

xlookup
A2:xlookup("?*",index(A:A&""),A:A,,2,-1)



"Note that the output of index can be used as range arguments"

Is it not OK to provide solutions that's broader & meet both the requirements?!

the match part is obtaining the row index as OP asked for in the question!

OP wants row index of last non-empty cell, which is what both the formulas are effectively supplying.

As said earlier: row index is being supplied as part of the formula

As said in my earlier comments, I really don't see the necessity to make any edits. You are welcome to disregard/downvote this answer if its not to the standards & just move on...

OP wants last non-empty cell row index → the formula clearly provides that within a setting of creating a range reference which inherently addresses the OPs main question. You too have been here long enough to know that there's nothing wrong with providing a bit more info that what was asked for as long as the main question is addressed as part of the whole thing.
